# Delete rows on linked spreadsheet when criteria is met

Tags: excel

I am creating a new spreadsheet that refers to information in a separate worksheet. I need rows to be removed from the new spreadsheet when certain criteria are met in the original spreadsheet. Using the example below, I am linking to the spreadsheet on the right and when there is a figure in the Amt Billed column, I want that row removed from the linked spreadsheet on the right.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how savvy you are with VBA macros it can be done fairly easily. The macro could be written in either of the two spreadsheets depending on which one you prefer.

Let's assume you do it in the right one. You have to open the developer tab in Excel and add a button which will be used to check the other spreadsheet. Right click and assign a new macro to it. In the macro (called a subroutine or sub) you have to write a code to go through each PO Iin the right spreadsheet and search for it in the other one, then cheching the column with the amounts. If not empty then delete the row in the right side spreadsheet. 
There are many tutorials online that give you chunks of code that you can stitch together.